# trigger style changes all the styles of an element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to change the background color of `Expanders` by using *style triggers* and it works but it changes all the original style of `Expander`.

I am using Material design in XAML expander and when i just try to change background color of `Expander`, it changes the `Expander` style completely .
please help me how i can change only one style and not all the styles of an element when using style triggers.

**Style Trigger**

```
<Style x:Key="ExpenderColor" TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Applying Style**

```
 <Expander Style="{DynamicResource ExpenderColor}" Margin="0 5 0 0" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Expander.Header>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" />
            <TextBlock Margin="15 0 0 0">DASHBOARD</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
 </Expander>
```

**Images**

**Original Material Design Expander**
[image: origional meterial design expander]

**After adding style property**
[image: After adding style property]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}"` to your *ExpenderColor* style.

```
<Style x:Key="ExpenderColor" TargetType="Expander" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="black"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"> </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```